# Схема предложения

Tags: синтаксис

"Тогда может быть все не правда, и разговоры о книгах, и советы отца, и споры за ужином? Все, все не правда!"

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, напишем эти предолжения грамотно: "Тогда, может быть, все неправда: и разговоры о книгах, и советы отца, и споры за ужином? Все, все неправда!" Во-вторых, заметим, что здесь два преложения: первое - простое, осложненное однородными членами предложения. Второе - простое, неосложненное. Грамматическая основа первого из предложений - "все(разговоры, советы,споры) неправда ", где "все(разговоры, советы,споры)" -подлежащее, "неправда " - сказуемое. Во втором предложении подлежащее - все, сказуемое (составное именное) - неправда. Это Вам нужно было?